# How to pre-select a value in a Select that is dynamically loaded in Material Design Lite?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select, material-design-lite

I'm building an app in MDL and I'm having an issue while selecting dynamically a value from the select, I'm using this plugin:

http://creativeit.github.io/getmdl-select/

This is an example of what I've tried and one of my ideas that it didn't work, I tried to select the the value and upgrading all again, but it didn't work. If you predefined the value, it will work, unfortunately there is a value that I get from a database and I cannot predefined it until it's fully loaded and the service provide me the result.

```js
$($('.mdl-menu__item')[1]).data("selected", "true");
componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/getmdl-select@2.0.1/getmdl-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/getmdl-select@2.0.1/getmdl-select.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- Simple Select -->
<div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield getmdl-select">
  <input type="text" value="" class="mdl-textfield__input" id="sample1" readonly>
  <input type="hidden" value="" name="sample1">
  <label for="sample1" class="mdl-textfield__label">Country</label>
  <ul for="sample1" class="mdl-menu mdl-menu--bottom-left mdl-js-menu">
    <li class="mdl-menu__item" data-val="DEU">Germany</li>
    <li class="mdl-menu__item" data-val="BLR">Belarus</li>
    <li class="mdl-menu__item" data-val="RUS">Russia</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<!-- Simple Select -->
<div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield getmdl-select">
  <input type="text" value="" class="mdl-textfield__input" id="sample2" readonly>
  <input type="hidden" value="" name="sample2">
  <label for="sample2" class="mdl-textfield__label">Country</label>
  <ul for="sample2" class="mdl-menu mdl-menu--bottom-left mdl-js-menu">
    <li class="mdl-menu__item" data-val="DEU" data-selected="true">Germany</li>
    <li class="mdl-menu__item" data-val="BLR">Belarus</li>
    <li class="mdl-menu__item" data-val="RUS">Russia</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Any idea if it's possible to load it dynamically? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer in Redit:
https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/b1furp/how_to_preselect_a_value_in_a_select_that_is/

And the solution works, the changes are needed:

1. To add an ID to the main Div.
2. Re-init the Div.

Here is the example working.

```js
$('.mdl-menu__item').eq(1).attr("data-selected", "true");
getmdlSelect.init('#test');
componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/getmdl-select@2.0.1/getmdl-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/getmdl-select@2.0.1/getmdl-select.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- Simple Select -->
<div id="test" class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield getmdl-select">
  <input type="text" value="" class="mdl-textfield__input" id="sample1" readonly>
  <input type="hidden" value="" name="sample1">
  <label for="sample1" class="mdl-textfield__label">Country</label>
  <ul for="sample1" class="mdl-menu mdl-menu--bottom-left mdl-js-menu">
    <li class="mdl-menu__item" data-val="DEU">Germany</li>
    <li class="mdl-menu__item" data-val="BLR">Belarus</li>
    <li class="mdl-menu__item" data-val="RUS">Russia</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```